# How to stop chrome keeping asking mic permisions when using a local html file?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a local html file that records audio from the mic. The thing is that even after allowing mic access for the page Chrome keeps asking for the mic permission every time that I record audio. How can I get rid of it? Or maybe even pre allow mic access for the page 9or even any loacl page)?

Comment: there's a setting, very deep in the menu. IIRC, it's settings>privacy+security>Site Settings>View Permissions+data...>file:///>Microphone.

Comment: @dandavis I found it and changed it to Allow but I'm still asked all the time to allow the mic access.